# Optimizing memory game

Tags: javascript, optimization, game

Can anyone help me optimize my code? I really don't know what to do about all the var rectangles and `var` colors.

```
package PO;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

var rectangle1: Rectangle;
var rectangle2: Rectangle;
var rectangle3: Rectangle;
var rectangle4: Rectangle;
var rectangle5: Rectangle;
var rectangle6: Rectangle;
var rectangle7: Rectangle;
var rectangle8: Rectangle;
var rectangle9: Rectangle;
var rectangle10: Rectangle;
var rectangle11: Rectangle;
var rectangle12: Rectangle;
var rectangle13: Rectangle;
var rectangle14: Rectangle;
var rectangle15: Rectangle;
var rectangle16: Rectangle;
var kleur1 = "red";
var kleur2 = "red";
var kleur3 = "red";
var kleur4 = "red";
var kleur5 = "red";
var kleur6 = "red";
var kleur7 = "red";
var kleur8 = "red";
var kleur9 = "red";
var kleur10 = "red";
var kleur11 = "red";
var kleur12 = "red";
var kleur13 = "red";
var kleur14 = "red";
var kleur15 = "red";
var kleur16 = "red";
var tekst = "beginnen maar";
var aantalclicks = 0;
var kaartkeuze = ["",""];
var scene: Scene;
var button: Button;

function KaartControle (){
    if (aantalclicks == 2){
        if(kaartkeuze [0] == kaartkeuze[1]){
            tekst = "goed bezig!";
            aantalclicks = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (aantalclicks == 3) {
        tekst = "jammer!";
        kleur1 = "red";
        kleur2 = "red";
        kleur3 = "red";
        kleur4 = "red";
        kleur5 = "red";
        kleur6 = "red";
        kleur7 = "red";
        kleur8 = "red";
        kleur9 = "red";
        kleur10 = "red";
        kleur11 = "red";
        kleur12 = "red";
        kleur13 = "red";
        kleur14 = "red";
        kleur15 = "red";
        kleur16 = "red";
        aantalclicks = 0;
    }
}

Stage {
    title: "Memory"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 500
        height: 300
        content: [
            Text {
                font: Font {
                    size: 16
                }
                x: 10
                y: 30
                content: bind tekst;
            }
            button = Button {
                translateX: 300
                translateY: 150
                text: "reset"
                visible: true
                action: function() {
                    kleur1 = "red";
                    kleur2 = "red";
                    kleur3 = "red";
                    kleur4 = "red";
                    kleur5 = "red";
                    kleur6 = "red";
                    kleur7 = "red";
                    kleur8 = "red";
                    kleur9 = "red";
                    kleur10 = "red";
                    kleur11 = "red";
                    kleur12 = "red";
                    kleur13 = "red";
                    kleur14 = "red";
                    kleur15 = "red";
                    kleur16 = "red";
                    aantalclicks = 0;
                }
            }
            //Kaart 1
            rectangle1 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur1)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur1 == "red"){
                        kleur1 = "green";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="1";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 2
            rectangle2 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur2)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur2 == "red"){
                        kleur2 = "green";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="1";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 3
            rectangle3 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur3)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur3 == "red"){
                        kleur3 = "blue";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="2";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 4
            rectangle4 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur4)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur4 == "red"){
                        kleur4 = "blue";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="2";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 5
            rectangle5 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur5)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur5 == "red"){
                        kleur5 = "yellow";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="3";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 6
            rectangle6 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur6)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur6 == "red"){
                        kleur6 = "yellow";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="3";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 7
            rectangle7 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur7)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur7 == "red"){
                        kleur7 = "purple";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="4";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 8
            rectangle8 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur8)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur8 == "red"){
                        kleur8 = "purple";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="4";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 9
            rectangle9 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur9)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur9 == "red"){
                        kleur9 = "grey";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="5";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 10
            rectangle10 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur10)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur10 == "red"){
                        kleur10 = "grey";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="5";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 11
            rectangle11 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur11)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur11 == "red"){
                        kleur11 = "pink";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="6";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 12
            rectangle12 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur12)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur12 == "red"){
                        kleur12 = "pink";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="6";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 13
            rectangle13 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur13)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur13 == "red"){
                        kleur13 = "orange";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="7";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 14
            rectangle14 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur14)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur14 == "red"){
                        kleur14 = "orange";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="7";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 15
            rectangle15 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur15)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur15 == "red"){
                        kleur15 = "black";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="8";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 16
            rectangle16 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur16)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur16 == "red"){
                        kleur16 = "black";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="8";
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce a some of your code by declaring your Rectangles and colors (kleur) as arrays.  Then you could initialize (or reset) the kleur array elements within a loop.

For example:
Instead of

```
var rectangle1: Rectangle;
var rectangle2: Rectangle;
var rectangle3: Rectangle;
var rectangle4: Rectangle;
//...
```

try

```
var rectangle[16]: Rectangle;
```

and instead of

```
var kleur1 = "red";
var kleur2 = "red";
var kleur3 = "red";
//...
```

try

```
var kleur[16];
var x;
for (x=0; x<16; x++)
    kleur[x] = "red";
```

Then, wherever you say

```
kleur1
```

you can say

```
kleur[1]
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i should do that?

Comment: Okay.  I added a few code examples.

Comment: thank you :), but now it keeps telling me i forgot the ';' but it's there, exactly like you did

Comment: Could you please post your revised code above (as a revision to the original code)?  I'll see if I can spot the missing semicolon.

Comment: I did, but only changed the var's, not rest of the code, because there were '!' signs all the time

Comment: You also need to replace each kleur1 with kleur[1] and kleur2 with kleur[2], etc.   Same with rectangle1, etc